# Relationships between multiple aggregate roots

Tags: domain-driven-design

In many applications, I deal with users and finance companies (as an example) and I have long been struggling to model the relationship between the two according to Domain Driven Design principles.

In my system I can do the following:

- Add a user to an existing finance company.
- Add a finance company to an existing user.

I believe both are aggregate roots... Finance Company and User.

How do I model the relationship between the 2?  Is it FinanceCompany.Users? or User.FinanceCompanies?  Is it neither?  Or am I missing knowledge of some key DDD concept(s)?  The problem is if I choose one way over the other, the code is more understandable / clear from one aggregate root entry point, but not the other.  Sometimes there are cases where it makes more sense to navigate to a Finance Company and add users to it, and other times there are cases where it makes more sense to navigate to a specific user and add finance companies to the user.

Is there some better way to approach this, maybe through repository methods?  Is there some key concept I am not getting or understanding here?  It doesn't feel right to assume the relationship between Finance Company and User belongs under either of the 2 ARs.  When I store the relationship I have to store it in a table named FinanceCompanyUsers or UserFinanceCompanies, but it still doesn't seem clear.

Would I have code such as FinanceCompany.AddUser() and User.AddFinanceCompany()? or is there some completely different approach for relationships such as this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have already determined that both `User` and `FinanceCompany` are aggregates so each has its own life-cycle.

The problem with many domains is that we don't have a complete understanding of the relationships.  As another example we can take an `Order` and a `Product`.  Both are aggregates but would we have `Order.AddProduct()` or `Product.AddOrder()`?  In this case it seems pretty obvious in that an `Order` contains a limited subset of `Product` entries whereas a `Product` may very well contain many orders and we are not really too interested in that relationship since it is a rather weak relationship.  A `Product` can exist and be valid without any orders attached but an `Order` is pretty useless without at least one product entry.  This means that the `Order` has an invariant imposed in terms of its `OrderItem` entries.  In addition to this we have enough knowledge about this hackneyed example that we know we are going to need an *associative entity* (in relational theory speak) since we need additional information regarding the relationship and entering the fray would be our `OrderItem` table.  Curiously I have not seen it called `OrderProduct`.

The guidance I would suggest is to pick the most appropriate side.

However, if no side is a true winner and both aggregates can exist without a relationship to the other in terms of an invariant perhaps the relationship itself is an aggregate as you have certainly alluded to.  Perhaps it isn't only a `UserFinanceCompany` aggregate but perhaps there is a concept that is missing from the ubiquitous language that the domain experts refer to.  Perhaps something like `Auditor` or some such that represents that relationship.  This is akin to the `OrderItem` or `OrderLine` concept as opposed to `OrderProduct`.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth follow up.  The Order / OrderItem relationship is more like a header/detail relationship which makes more sense to use Order as the AR, whereas, in this case, there isn't a true "header" as it makes equal sense to start at either User or FinanceCompany as an entry point.  I think I will try "perhaps the relationship itself is an aggregate" and see how that feels, but I am still open to any other suggestions or information.  Thank you!

Comment: Update - Instead of UserFinanceCompany or FinanceCompanyUser, I went with "Permission".  This seems to make more sense now as its own AR, and I can "get permissions" by user or finance company.